# Excel VBA Format Initials & Date

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning,

I'm trying to have a set of initials and DOB combined into one column to make a unique identifier for each person. For example, Initials "JS" with DOB "01/01/2001" should output JS01012001. The DOB column is originally formatted as mm/dd/yyyy style. Before I do the concatenation, I reformat it as "mmddyyyy". This appears correctly in the DOB column. However, when I run the macro I have (below) it outputs as "JS01/01/2001" in the ID column. I'm trying every combination I can think of in the formatting to get it to output correctly, but I'm still not getting it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

```
' Format DOB column (M)
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mmddyyyy"

' Concatenate Initials (L) and DOB (M) columns and output in ID column (N)
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 12) & "" & Cells(i, 13)
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the date object into a string in VBA using:

```
Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 12) & Format(Cells(i, 13), "mmddyyyy")
```